# How and why did we extended the domain and definition of trigonometric function from the angles of right triangle to the angles of any triangle?

Tags: functions, trigonometry, triangles

Was it by the formula for $\sin(x+y)$, reference triangle or something? Which practical and mathematical problems required this extension?

Comment: The domain of trigonometric functions is not the (set of) right triangles, so it's hard to understand what the question actually means to ask.

Comment: Followup after OP's edit: trigonometric functions are defined for *angles*. Angles are defined by a pair of lines, *not* by triangles. The question still makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

All the trig functions are ratios defined in terms of angles. We can extend the domain of these functions beyond pure right triangles using the unit circle. We needed to extend them first to deal with the Law of Cosines and The Law of Sines, which extends the Pythagorean Theorem to deal with obtuse and acute triangles. We also use trig functions to model periodic events, like the temperature throughout the year. Finally, we use trig functions throughtout Calculus for things like Fourier Transforms.